# widget covered by keyboard in MobileFirst hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, soft-keyboard, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a simple MobileFirst hybrid app with only html/JS. On iOS7, when inputting data for a widget near the bottom of the screen, the widget becomes covered by the soft keyboard. This happens only for the app. If run it in mobile browser, it doesn't happen.
On Android4.4.2, it happens in both mobile browser and the MobileFirst app. Noticed on Android, there is  AndroidManifest.xml file for MobileFirst app, so tried setting android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize", that doesn't help. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, try a combination of both:

- Try the following suggestion (from: [How to auto-scroll to input field in Android when the soft keyboard overlaps them on showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328156/how-to-auto-scroll-to-input-field-in-android-when-the-soft-keyboard-overlaps-the/)). Add
  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in AndroidManifest.xml, and
- `height=device-height` in the meta `viewport` tag in the HTML file's HEAD element

For iOS:

- You could use iScroll to scroll a bit when the specific element is focused so that it will be seen (see: [$.mobile.silentScroll does not work in worklight app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282802/mobile-silentscroll-does-not-work-in-worklight-app)), or
- You can try the suggestion provided here: [Textfield does not focus in UI WebView in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542470/textfield-does-not-focus-in-ui-webview-in-ios7)

Comment: I have tried your suggestions, for Android, your suggestion didn't work. We are still looking for solutions. For iOS, after add viewpoint meta tag: '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' and apple's meta tag: '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">', the problem is fixed.